# Visualize/plot the morphological structuring element in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Someone can help to visualize or plot the morphological structuring element, created by function 'strel' for only 'disk' structuring, in Matlab? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a big strange, but I assume that for efficiency reasons, `strel` returns a special type that's a structuring element type.

[You have to use the getnhood function as in this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/f3-23960.html#f3-21198), something like this:

```
  se3 = strel('disk',15);
  nhood = getnhood(se3);
  imagesc(nhood); axis xy; colormap('gray');
```