# casting strel to double in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, casting

How can I do a cast of strel to double in MATLAB?
I tried several casts without success.
I couldn't find anything that worked.
thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visualize/plot the morphological structuring element in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862707/visualize-plot-the-morphological-structuring-element-in-matlab)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [GETNHOOD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/getnhood.html) method of the structuring element:

```
se = strel('diamond',3)
nhood = se.getnhood
nhood =
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0

%# cast to double
nhood = double(nhood);
```

Comment: @yoda: I made a mistake in my initial answer. It's the `getnhood` method that produces a logical output that can be cast to `double`.

Comment: @yes, I was just about to answer with that :) +1